# Selenium python not working when user interacted the screen by enter / submit click

Tags: python-3.x

I am using selenium binding with python code. I am capturing the login details from user and selenium will continue to proceed the further screens. However if user entered any enter key  and clicked the submit manually, selenium closing the driver with errors.

Is that any way to handle selenium to work based on user interaction in python.

Example , let me say a registration screen ,  selenium will fill the registration for and waiting for user to validate the data and submit it/Press enter to submit by user.

Any alternates are available for selenium web form filling with python.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This case has been resolved. As there is dual submit happened from manually as well as from selenium. Currently removed the selenium submit in python code and user able to give manual submit without issues. Also added the below wait time for user submission , until the page redirects.

```
       while  driver.current_url.find(vloginurl)!=-1:
          time.sleep(vwaittime)
```